# Is there a way to tell that a user converted from a free trial using App Store server notifications?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, storekit

I have App Store server notifications enabled so I get a ping whenever user status changes, but is there a way to tell when a user unlocked for instance a two week trial, then two weeks later when the trial is over and the subscription unlocks, is there a way to tell that event versus just a "normal" renewal?